# SQL notation/variable name

Tags: sql

Suppose we have summary table called  `summary`  with the following fields:  `date` ,  `user_id` ,  `song_id`  and  `count` . It shows at the end of each day how many times in her history a user has listened to a given song.

A second table called  `daily`  records whether a user listens to a particular song. This table is used to update the first table. If a song is in the  `daily`  table but not in the  `summary`  table, then a new record is created in the  `summary`  table with the appropriate counts.

**Question/Problem** I am looking through some sample solutions and was not sure about the particular notation in this answer:

```
SELECT A.USERID, A.SONG, SUM(A.COUNT) COUNT
FROM
(SELECT USERID, SONG, COUNT FROM SUMMARY
UNION ALL
SELECT USERID, SONG, COUNT FROM DAILY WHERE DATE = NOW()) A
GROUP BY A.USERID, A.SONG
```

Why is there a  `COUNT`  beside  `A.COUNT`  in the following line:  `SUM(A.COUNT) COUNT` ? Likewise, where is there an  `A`  after  `DATE = NOW())`  in the following line:  `WHERE DATE = NOW()) A` ?

Comment: Those are _aliases_.  They give names to columns or subqueries so they can be referenced in other places.

Comment: It's an alias.  In the case of the column, it's naming the `SUM(A.COUNT)` column `COUNT`, and in the case of the `A`, it's aliasing the sub-query to `A` to be referenced by `A.ColumnName`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an alias.  The example is aliasing a table or field name to something else (in this case, `A`).

Official MySQL documentation will help you here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Quoting (emphasis added by me):

> A `select_expr` can be given an alias using `AS alias_name`. The alias is
>   used as the expression's column name and can be used in `GROUP BY`,
>   `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses. For example:
>
> `SELECT CONCAT(last_name, ', ', first_name) AS full_name FROM mytable ORDER BY full_name;`
>
> The `AS` keyword is **optional** when aliasing a
>   select_expr with an identifier. The preceding example could have been
>   written like this:
>
> `SELECT CONCAT(last_name, ', ', first_name) full_name FROM mytable ORDER BY full_name;`

Comment: Doh - assuming it's MySQL you're using!  See the appropriate *SQL documentation if you're not - but it'll be the same thing :-)

Answer (score 0):

These are known as **Aliases** and simply rename the column. In the case of the Sum(A.Count) this is required as the output of a function has no column name.

This is equivilent to writing

```
SUM(A.Count) AS Count,
```

Or

```
SUM(A.Count) "Count",
```